# Trying to get jacoco report for my project using jenkins. But its giving wrong report. it includes __cobertura* methods also

Tags: jenkins, java-8, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am trying to get jacoco report for my project using jenkins. But its giving wrong report. it includes __cobertura* methods also.

effective pom     [here](https://ksudha1988.blogspot.in/2017/03/effective-pom.html)

I am getting correct report using maven install from eclipse.
But if I build using jenkins for the same class I am getting weird results. It includes __copertura generated methods. and there are huge difference in the other method coverages too. can I get the same result as I am getting in eclipse ?
[click][2]

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aojJ7.png
```

Comment: Can you post a full POM with `help:effective-pom` from Jenkins and local? In this there is no hint to cobertura.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
hi christophergave the effective pom

https://ksudha1988.blogspot.in/2017/03/effective-pom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

gave this maven command in jenkins

-B -U clean install cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml pmd:pmd pmd:cpd findbugs:findbugs

now removed and gave -B -U clean install  alone. its working now